# PDO/Mysql PHP Recursive category Tree with showing all items

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Afternoon,

I am using a recursive function to get a list of items from a data table. But if the results are more than 2000 it seems to make 'mysql go away'.

I have split the database into 3 tables :

```
menu = category_id,category,parent_id

item_categories = item_id,category_id

item_info = item_id,price etc..
```

All the _ids are integers only.

The issue I have is there is 7000 categories at present with sub-levels up to 7 deep.

There are around 80000 items at present which can be in multiple categories.
The database is for quite-specific boiler spares department.

When a category is chosen I would like to count all items in the category and all of their sub categories as well as sort them by price. I need to get a total count for pagination, but i only wish to display about 50 results per page which i sort either by price ASC or price DESC depending on client choice.

To try to allow the page load to look nice and give it a little extra time I am loading the page then once loaded it calls the itemview page via jquery, with a loader on screen until results are returned. When 'mysql goes away' the loader just stays on screen..

I am using PDO with mysql, with PHP.
I have the ids indexed in all 3 data tables.

any guidance would be appreciated..

Comment: I think AJAX would be the best solution, because as I guess you don't output every one of 80000 items, so you group them somehow, and if user opens a group (maybe category) just load this category only. I don't know jquery, so maybe you're doing this that way, so sorry then to bother.

Comment: are you fetching the entire parts tree on every request? using multiple queries? if so, you'd be better off doing a single `select *` and building your tree PHP-side.